# Elements inside JQuery dialog are too big

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page which uses JQuery and opens a dialog when a specific button is pressed. But the problem is that the content and the dialog itself are TOO big. I know that in JQuery I can adjust the size of dialog(which I actually did by setting width to 1500, otherwise it would appear sliced in the middle), but the content?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dialogAddPartDiv = $('#dialogAddPart');

  $('#showDialogButton').click(function() {
    dialogAddPartDiv.dialog('open');
  });

  dialogAddPartDiv.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      'Save': function() {}
    },
    beforeClose: function(event) {
      if (!confirm("It won't be saved. Continue?")) {
        return false;
      } else {}
    },
    width: 1500
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<body>


  <button type="button" id="showDialogButton">+Show Dialog</button>

  <div id="dialogAddPart">

    <table>

      <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" size="80" value=""></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Test:</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" size="80" value=""></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
      </tr>


    </table>

  </div>

</body>
```

You see that the dialog size(and content inside) are the way bigger than the button. How can I set it right?

Comment: You are setting `size` attribute, isn't that all your problem?!

Comment: There is only 'resize' attribute available

Comment: `size="65"` ?! What resize are you talking about?

Comment: it's the size of an input field, not the div or table size

Comment: It is a CSS related issue. `#dialogAddPart { font-size: medium; }` should help.

Comment: Unfortunetely, it didn't :c

Comment: @RobertBaratheon Ya it is and so container takes enough space to display it. Now i've no idea what is your issue/question?!

Comment: Ok, how can I set div or table size to very small in such a way that in dialog it is displayed small too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table is bigger is size because of this attr which you are using

```
size="85"
```

Table by default takes the max value for all column defined in your case "85"

Just remove them and try, it works fine

http://jsfiddle.net/Zrz9t/4000/